# Long Ubuntu 20.04 wake up time

Tags: 20.04

I have been running Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot on a MacBook Air (mid 2013) from a USB flash drive extremely well for the last few months with only one annoyance – when opening the lid it can take up to approx 25 seconds for the login screen to appear. sometimes the login screen can appear instantly, but more often than not it takes a long time.
I have just partitioned the SSD on the MacBook Air an installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside the MacOS in the hope that this would improve the wake up time, but unfortunately there is no improvement.
I have noticed that on the occasions the login screen appeared instantly that I had to wait for an internet connection to be established, but when it takes 25 seconds for the login screen to appear the internet connection has already up and running.
Note that if I boot into MacOS the wake up time is always instantaneous.
Any help or advice resolving this annoyance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sudo journalctl --since="-3 minutes"` will show hints.

Comment: Hi waltinator. Thank you for the advice - as a relative newbie to ubuntu I'm still fumbling around finding out how to do things. I ran the above in terminal and the delay appears to be associated with the MacBook Air kernel and usb as per the following: 
Sep 29 09:38:19 djr-MacBookAir kernel: usb usb2-port3: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Sep 29 09:38:19 djr-MacBookAir kernel: usb usb2-port3: attempt power cycle
Sep 29 09:38:19 djr-MacBookAir kernel: usb usb2-port3: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad? Any further help would be appreciated

Comment: Hey David Roberts! What do you mean by "_MacBook Air **an** installed_"? Is it "an" or "and"?  If it's a typo, please do correct the spelling by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]